# Multiprocessing gets stuck on join in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I have a script that collects data from a database, filters and puts into list for further processing. I've split entries in the database between several processes to make the filtering faster. Here's the snippet:

```
def get_entry(pN,q,entries_indicies):

    ##collecting and filtering data
    q.put((address,page_text,))
    print("Process %d finished!" % pN)

def main():

    #getting entries
    data = []

    procs = []
    for i in range(MAX_PROCESSES):
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=get_entry,args=(i,q,entries_indicies[i::MAX_PROCESSES],))
        procs += [(p,q,)]
        p.start()       
    for i in procs:
        i[0].join()
        while not i[1].empty():
            #process returns a tuple (address,full data,)
            data += [i[1].get()]
    print("Finished processing database!")

    #More tasks
    #................
```

I've run it on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and it went totally fine. The problems start when I run it on Windows 7. The script gets stuck on `i[0].join()` for 11th process out of 16 (which looks totally random to me). No error messages, nothing, just freezes there. At the same time, the `print("Process %d finished!" % pN)` is displayed for all processes, which means they all come to an end, so there should be no problems with the code of `get_entry`

I tried to comment the `q.put` line in the process function, and it all went through fine (well, of course, `data` ended up empty).

Does it mean that `Queue` here is to blame? Why does it make `join()` stuck? Is it because of internal `Lock` within `Queue`? And if so, and if `Queue` renders my script unusable on Windows, is there some other way to pass data collected by processes to `data` list in the main process?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with an answer to my last question.

I use `Manager` instead

```
def get_entry(pN,q,entries_indicies):
    #processing

    # assignment to manager list in another process doesn't work, but appending does.
    q += result

def main():

    #blahbalh

    #getting entries
    data = []

    procs = []
    for i in range(MAX_PROCESSES):
        manager = Manager()
        q = manager.list()
        p = Process(target=get_entry,args=(i,q,entries_indicies[i::MAX_PROCESSES],))
        procs += [(p,q,)]
        p.start()
    # input("Press enter when all processes finish")
    for i in procs:
        i[0].join()
        data += i[1]
    print("data", data)#debug
    print("Finished processing database!")

    #more stuff
```

The nature of freezing in Windows on `join()` due to presence of `Queue` still remains a mystery. So the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) says,

> Warning As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the pipe.
>   This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue have been consumed. Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its non-daemonic children.
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue. See Programming guidelines.

So, since the `multiprocessing.Queue` is a kind of `Pipe`, when you call `.join()`, there are some items in the queue, and you should consume then or simply `.get()` them to make the empty. Then call `.close()` and `.join_thread()` for each queue.

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948595/5046896).